# A fractional Gronwall lemma

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, partial-differential-equations, integral-inequality

I have an energy estimate of the form
$$\dot{u} + \lambda u^{1+ \delta} \le C (1+t)^{-\sigma},$$
where $u=u(t)$ is positive, $\lambda, \delta > 0$ and one can assume $\sigma > 1$ large. I expect the solution to satisfy a bound of the form
$$u \le M\Big(C + u(0)\Big)(1+t)^{-1 / \delta}$$
for some universal $M > 0$.
The only answer I found online is Proposition 2.2 of *New nonlinear inequalities and application to control systems* by Ghrissi and Hammami. However, they use a lemma which corresponds to the kind of Gronwall inequality I need but for $\lambda \le 0$,
and I did not manage to adapt the proof.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out how to prove the bound I was looking for. I drew inspiration from the *alternative proof of Lemma 3.2* taken from [S. Mischler's course on evolution PDEs (first chapter, dedicated to Gronwall's lemma)](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/%7Emischler/lespagesHTML/M2Evolution2020.html).

The key trick is the following inequality valid for any $u, \ell, \delta > 0$:
$$u \le u \left( \frac{u}{\ell} \right)^{\delta} + \ell,$$
which in turn implies for any $a > 0$ (simply consider $a := \ell^{\delta}$)
$$a u \le u^{1+\delta} + a^{1+1 / \delta}.$$
**Note that this holds for any $a$ and therefore any function $a=a(t) > 0$,** thus we can plug this lower bound in the differential inequality as to obtain a linear one with a source term which we can partly choose and then optimize!

\begin{align}
\dot{u} + \lambda a u &\le C (1+ t )^{-\sigma} + \lambda a^{1+1/\delta}
\end{align}
$$u \le e^{-\lambda A(t)} u(0) + e^{-\lambda A(t)} \int_0^t e^{\lambda A(t')} \Big\{ C (1+t')^{-\sigma} + \lambda a(t')^{1+1/\delta} \Big\} d t',$$
where we denoted $A(t)=\int_0^t a(t') d t'$. Choosing $a(t)=\frac{\delta + 1}{\delta \lambda (1 + t)}$ we get
\begin{align}
u &\le (1 + t)^{-1-1/\delta} u(0) + (1+t)^{-1-1/\delta} \int_0^t \left\{C (1+t')^{1+1/\delta - \sigma} + \lambda \left(\frac{1+\delta}{\delta \lambda}\right)^{1+1/\delta} (1+t')^{-1-1/\delta} \right\} d t'\\
& \le (1 + t)^{-1-1/\delta} u(0) + \frac{C \delta}{1+\delta(2-\sigma)} (1+t)^{1-\sigma} + \lambda\delta \left(\frac{1+\delta}{\lambda}\right)^{1+1/\delta} (1+t)^{-1/\delta}.
\end{align}
In particular, the optimal decay rate is obtained for $\sigma \ge 1+1/\delta$ and we have
$$u \le (M + u(0)) (1+t)^{-1-1/\delta}, ~ M := \frac{C \delta}{1+\delta(2-\sigma)} + \lambda\delta \left(\frac{1+\delta}{\lambda}\right)^{1+1/\delta}.$$

*N.B.* In my case, $\lambda \approx u(0)^{-\delta}$ so when $\sigma \ge 1+1/\delta$, there holds indeed
$$u \lesssim (C + u(0))(1+t)^{-1/\delta}.$$